# Azure Function call local Function on Webserver

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions

I want to have a Azure Function that can trigger a function on my local running server. I am using .NET 6.0 as local server.

The detailed issue is, that, I want to create a function-website in Azure like:
`demowebpagexx.azurewebsites.net`, that has an endpoint with a form like `\HttpExample?param1=HelloWorld`.

Now, this form should be submitted to my local server in this function e.g.:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class demowebpagexx : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet(Name = "demowebpagexx")]
    public void demowebpagexx(String param1)
    {
        Trace.Write($"Param1 is {param1}");
    }
}
```

I know, that i can host the webserver online, but this is not what i want to do, because I only would need this call with this single parameter.

Comment: It sounds like you want to run locally because it's only 1 parameter so you think it's not worth paying to cloud host it. Is that your only reason? If so, consider writing it as an Azure Function and use Consumption plan - because Azure hosting on Consumption plan is likely to be cost-free if you have a very simple use-case. Is there a reason you wouldn't do that?

Comment: @AndrewB: so I need to host the full server and then I would have to pay the full consumption on the server --> or can I have like a hybrid solution?

Comment: Can you give more description of what your Endpoint does? If it's super simple, then Consumption plan is free-of-charge (other than a very small charge for storage) https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/details/functions/

Comment: @AndrewB: Endpoint for Appointment Scheduler -> it is giving the users SSE and is syncing two databases (DB2 and azure SQL). As I calculated, there would be like 10.000 API Calls every day for the whole system.
In my question I want to create a trigger for the DB2 on some tables, so I can reduce the api calls for better sync (now I am querying the tables every minute...)

Comment: If you're already paying for Azure SQL, and your Endpoint is very simple, then the extra cost for that Endpoint will be almost insignificant perhaps. Basically if most of your platform is in Azure, then I think it doesn't make sense to try and run your API locally just for saving a small amount of Azure resource cost. You haven't really asked a specific question around that though, and I realise you just wanted to know if it was possible! So sorry this isn't an answer to that.